# Django doesn't keep User logged in between views

Tags: python, ajax, django, csrf

I am quite new to web programming and django especially. I am trying to implement symple login service using Ajax. The user seems to be logged in succesfully however when the view is changed he uppears ulogged again.

Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Login template:

```
<form class="login-form" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" id="usernamelog" />
  <input type="password" id="pwdlogin" />
  <button onclick="login(event)">login</button>
  <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
</form>
```

Login Ajax:

```
function login(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var username = $("#usernamelog").val();
        var pwd = $("#pwdlogin").val();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                    // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
                }
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url : "/loginscript/",
            type : "post",
            data : {
                username: username,
                password : pwd,
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            if (data == "good") {
                document.getElementById('usernamelog').value ="good";
                window.location='../ehealth'
            }else{
                document.getElementById('usernamelog').value ="bad";
            }
        });
    }


    function getCookie(name) {
         var cookieValue = null;
         if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
             var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
             for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                 var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                 // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                 if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                     cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
         return cookieValue;
     }
```

Loginscript view:

```
def loginscript(request):
#c = {}
#c.update(csrf(request))
print >> sys.stderr,"script entered"
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
print >> sys.stderr, username
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    login(request=request,user=user)
    if User.is_authenticated:
        print >> sys.stderr,"should be good actually"
    else:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Still not"
    return HttpResponse("good")

else:
    print >> sys.stderr,"Should be bad"
    return HttpResponse("bad")
```

Ehealth view:

```
def index(request):
check=User.is_authenticated
if check!=True:
    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/')

template="index.html"
return render (request=request, template_name=template)
```

The log I get:

```
Hey we are in login
[04/Oct/2016 14:02:42] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6881
script entered
Andrey
should be good actually
[04/Oct/2016 14:02:46] "POST /loginscript/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4
[04/Oct/2016 14:02:46] "GET /ehealth/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Hey we are in login
```

So the user is logged in and then redirected back to login page as unlogged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User.is_authenticated` is always true by definition, because you're calling it on the class. You need to check the method on the actual user instance: in your login view that is `user`, but in the index view that will be `request.user`.

However an even easier way to check the authentication in the index view is to use the [`login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Answer (score 2):

Use this code snippet:

```
    def index(request):          
      if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/')

      template="index.html"
      return render (request=request, template_name=template)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a number of problems with your code.

1. You're calling (no not calling, I'll get to that) [`is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) from the user class (*Capital U* in `User`) and not from the user instance which you're trying to log in i.e. `user.is_authenticated`.
2. The `is_authenticated` attribute is a method in versions of Django < 1.10. If you're with a version less than 1.10, you should call the method using double parenthesis